# Intel HAXM install hangs on macOS Sierra

Tags: android, intel, macos-sierra, haxm

I'm trying to install HAXM 6.2.1 on a MacBook Pro running MacOS Sierra, but the installer hangs.

Attempting to install via the GUI .dmg, the dialog "This package will run a program to determine if the software can be installed" appears. I click "Continue," and then the installer hangs. The dialog does not disappear, but cannot be moved or dismissed.

Attempting to install via the command line installer simply hangs with no further information.

Attempting to install via the command line `silent install,` the installer hangs with the `haxm-isRunning` process active. Googling for "haxm-isRunning" yields 0 results.

No log file appears to be generated. No console entries are found containing the string "haxm," so I think there are no relevant console entries either.

I'm at a loss and not sure what else to try. Any advice or suggestions?

Comment: Hung for a bit but after a couple minutes it finished successfully for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem.  HAXM installation would never exit and had to use "force quit" in order to kill it.

Found a log message in `/var/log/system.log` that seemed to coincide with the installation.  It was from a totally different application but the same error reoccurred each time I tried to run the HAXM installer:

```
... com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.paloaltonetworks.authorized[284]): Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 sent by exc handler[0]
```

The errors referred to a daemon called "authorized" from paloaltonetworks.  Every time I tried to run the HAXM installer I would see a Segmentation Fault error logged related to the authorized daemon.

So I disabled the authorized daemon temporarily by editing the `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.paloaltonetworks.authorized.plist` file and set **RunAtLoad to false** as well as **KeepAlive to false** and rebooted.  Probably would have been enough to unload and reload the daemon via launchctl but whatever.

After rebooting with the authorized daemon disabled I was able to successfully install HAXM.  No issues.

Then I re-enabled the authorized daemon by reverting the changes to `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.paloaltonetworks.authorized.plist` and rebooted.

Palo Alto Networks Traps (authorized daemon is related to this application) tool is working and HAXM is installed.  All good.  Hope this helps.

Comment: This was exactly what was happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

BTW -- it traps is indeed your problem (and it was for me) you can also just disable from the command line the traps stuff if you can sudo.

```
$ sudo bash
# cd /Library/Application Support/PaloAltoNetworks/Traps/bin
# ./cytool runtime stop all
--- INSTALL HAXM and whatever else ---
# ./cytool runtime start all
```

That should do the trick without having to reboot, etc.